# TypeError req.status is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, pug, nodemon

I am getting an error and that error is

```
TypeError: req.status is not a function
at E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\app.js:11:6
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

And the code in which i am getting error is:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

And the directory in which i am working, in that directory i have installed express, pug, nodemon. If anybody knows what to do let me know in the comments or answer

```
app.get("/demo", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render('demo', {title: 'Hey there!', message: 'Kya chal raha hai'})
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("<p>Rocket Launched succesfully<br></p>")
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    res.send("<p>About<br>We are human being</p>")
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, you type `req` intead `res` somewhere. [Req object](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) really doesnt have status method

Comment: @UnKnOwN_12 Yes, i can: `at E:\Creations\Languages\HTml\HTML\experiment\app.js:11:6`

Comment: but in app.js line 11 character 6 it is already res.send()